# IRC BOT in Python, if in elif in while-loop

Tags: python, chat, bots, irc

Here is the complete code:

```
#client der mit irc-server kontakt aufnimmt
import time
import socket
from sys import argv

script, mitspieler1, mitspieler2 = argv
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

class funktion:

    def main(self):

            print "Socket(Client)"
            host = "irc.iz-smart.net"
            port = 6667 
            PASS = "7987fshd" 
            NICK = "Testikus" 
            USER = "Testikus localhost irc.iz-smart.net :Testikus" 
            self.login(PASS, NICK, USER, host, port)
            print "Verbindung aufgebaut zu {0}(IP:{1})".format(
            host, socket.gethostbyname(host)
            )
            self.haupt_schleife()

    def haupt_schleife(self):
        while True:
            antwort = sock.recv(4096)
            join = "JOIN #testblablub \r\n"
            print antwort
            if antwort[0:4] == "PING":
                self.pong(antwort, join)
            elif antwort.split()[3] == ":quiz.start":
                sock.sendall("PRIVMSG #testblablub Es spielen mit: "
                            +mitspieler1+" und "+mitspieler2+"\r\n"
                            )
                time.sleep(2)
                self.fragen(antwort)

    def pong(self, antwort, join):
        sock.sendall("PONG " + antwort.split()[1] + "\n")
        time.sleep(3)
        sock.sendall(join)
        sock.sendall("PRIVMSG #testblablub hi \r\n")

    def login(self, PASS, NICK, USER, host, port):
        sock.connect((host, port))
        sock.sendall("PASS "+PASS+"\n")
        sock.sendall("NICK "+NICK+"\n")
        sock.sendall("USER "+USER+"\n")

    def fragen(self, antwort):
            sock.sendall("PRIVMSG #testblablub Welche Farbe hat der Himmel ? \r\n")
            time.sleep(3)
            if antwort.split()[3] == ":blau":
                sock.sendall("PRIVMSG #testblablub RISCHTISCH \r\n")





ausfuehren = funktion()
ausfuehren.main()
```

(sry some strings are written in german, but I think that's not important)

So my main problem is that I want the function `def fragen(self, antwort)` to be run in the `def haupt_schleife(self)` function (or method for python's sake). All of the important stuff is in this `def haupt_schleife(self)`. I want that the rest of the quiz-code to be running in the elif-block of the `def haupt_schleife(self)`, so that it's a complete seperate thing. The stupid thing is, if I type in "quiz.start" the : `sock.sendall("PRIVMSG #testblablub Welche Farbe hat der Himmel ? \r\n")` is running with no problems, but it doesn't start the if-statement. It just does nothing else in the channel (just prints "Welche Farbe hat der Himmel ? out).

I hope that finaly someone understood this :/ 
(if you want to run the code you have to type in two names in the command line, because of argv)

Comment: For future references, output doesn't matter all that much but variable name WOULD be nice if they were written in English. I'm not saying it's a requirement to get help but many people might get picky and just ignore the code because of it so to increase your odds by writing all variables in English :) Jedenfalls, viel Glück :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## IRC syntax

Sending messages should **not** be done this way:

```
PRIVMSG #testblablub Es spielen mit:
```

It should be:

```
PRIVMSG #testblablub :Es spielen mit ...
```

Also, `USER` should consist of 4 parts:

```
<username> <hostname> <servername> :<full name/realname>
```

In irc, it's **important** to end each string with `\r\n`
I noticed you sent `\n` sometimes and that will end badly, always end with `\r\n`!

Then comes `sock.sendall(...)`, it's supposed to be used on say UDP sockets where you want to broadcast a message on all open sockets, in your case you're sending to and from a server, nothing else.. and it's via TCP so you should be using `sock.send(...)` (correct me if i'm wrong here)

A side note:
`PING`, it should only reply with `PONG <server-name (usually sent with PING)>\r\n` and not be spammed with `JOIN` every time, `JOIN` should be sent after MOTD is recieved, but sure it's not a problem really.. it will only annoy the sysadmins.
In your case it would probably be `PONG irc.iz-smart.net\r\n` and nothing else, no `JOIN` etc.

---

### Now, to the problem

```
   def haupt_schleife(self):
        while True:
            antwort = sock.recv(4096)
            join = "JOIN #testblablub \r\n"
            print antwort
            if antwort[0:4] == "PING":
                self.pong(antwort, join)
            elif antwort.split()[3] == ":quiz.start":
                sock.sendall("PRIVMSG #testblablub Es spielen mit: "
                            +mitspieler1+" und "+mitspieler2+"\r\n"
                            )
                time.sleep(2)
                self.fragen(antwort)
            elif antwort.split()[3] == ":blau":
                sock.sendall("PRIVMSG #testblablub RISCHTISH!\r\n")
```

Since `self.fragen(...)` **only** get called if the *user* writes `quiz.start`, the `if` check inside `def fragen(...)` will **never** be run again.. (because the next time the user write something, it's probably "blau" and that doesn't match ":quiz.start" which is the ONLY way in to the `if` check inside `fragen(...)`.

```
    def fragen(self, antwort):
            sock.sendall("PRIVMSG #testblablub Welche Farbe hat der Himmel ? \r\n")
            time.sleep(3)
```

So we removed the `if` block and made it an `elif` in `haupt_schleife` instead.

This is how the **FIRST** run/message would get parsed:
[image]

The next run, the message WOULD be green in `fragen` but it never reaches there because the only way to get there is via `elif antwort.split()[3] == ":quiz.start":` :)

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for the efford and all the details :) That helped me alot. But i think to do a really good quiz, if have to make a lot more complicated stuff, i will see what the future brings. And if i want to implement some other stuff, how can i avoid these if/elif caskades? I hate that.(Just a short answer maybe or so?) Greets

Comment: There's no "short" version of `if` caskades, when doing a quiz (string comparison) there will be a lot of them sorry to say.
One way to do it dynamic is via `self.questions = {'Welche farbe hat der Himmel?' : 'balu', 'Was is mein name?' : 'testikus', 'welcher tag ist es?' : 'freitag'} and so on. When "starting" a game, you could remember it in say `self.game = 'Was is mein name?' ` and for whatever answer the user gives you can do `if antwort == self.questions[self.question]:` and compare it dynamicly, only one if for all questions and answers :) Python dictionaries are awesome, google them :)

Comment: Don't forget to accept this as a solution IF (and only if) you think this solved your original problem and feel free to open up more if you need any assistance :)

Comment: Thank you :) but maybe i will switch to some other projects(for some time) and see what i can learn there. :) Greets

Answer (score 0):

You call the `fragen` function when this condition is true:

```
elif antwort.split()[3] == ":quiz.start":
```

Then, in the `fragen` function, you enter the `if` branch when this condition is true:

```
if antwort.split()[3] == ":blau":
```

Since the function got called, we know that `antwort.split()[3]` will be `":quiz.start"`, hence the `if` statement will never be executed.

You should recheck the logic behind your application.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply :) Is there any way to avoid these if/elif caskades??

Comment: Not to be rude but the only way to avoid them is not to write them.

Comment: or create a dictionary with questions matching answeres and keep it to one `if` statement. It's less with more, but it can quickly be complicated to read as a developer if you don't spill it out the way you're suggesting :) But there are other ways around if statements in this case.

Comment: Ok, i will kepp that in mind :) thx for your great help @Torexed !